# Google Chrome rendering problem whereas the code is working on IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

It should look like this - working on **IE**
[image]

but it is't showing like the above on **Google Chrome**:

[image]

Let me paste the codes I've been using :

**Structure :**

```
.header
|_ .h-box-style & .h-box-1
  |_.ad-title
  |_.ad-content
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
    <title>OrderBorder.com -- The way you want the deals for Apple mobile phones </title>
    <link href="styles/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript" language="javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="main">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="h-box-1 h-box-style">
                <span class="ad-title">Enjoy Group Savings</span>
                <div class="ad-content">
                    Wholesale prices for your Apple gear get lower with larger group size.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="h-box-2 h-box-style">
                <span class="ad-title">Earn Points</span>
                <div class="ad-content">
                    Keep earning points with every purchase you and your friends make.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="h-box-3 h-box-style">
                <span class="ad-title">Reach Borderline Prices</span>
                <div class="ad-content">
                    Eat my dust group!!! Use your points to bring your own prices to the border.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and **CSS Code:**

```
body
{
    margin:0px;
    background-image:url(../images/background.jpg);
}
 div.main
{
    background-image:url(../images/main_background.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:950px;
    width:897px;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
}

div.main div.header
{
    width:893px;
    height:120px;
    margin-top:120px;
    float:left;
}

div.main div.header div.h-box-style
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

div.main div.header div.h-box-style span.ad-title
{
    color:Black;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:20px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:Red;
}

div.main div.header div.h-box-style div.ad-content
{
    color:Gray;
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:12px;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
}   

div.main div.header div.h-box-1
{
    float:left;
    width:220px;
    height:80px;
    margin-left:80px;
    margin-top:20px;
}

div.main div.header div.h-box-2
{
    float:left;
    width:220px;
    height:80px;
    margin-left:70px;
    margin-top:20px;
}

div.main div.header div.h-box-3
{
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    height:80px;
    margin-left:30px;
    margin-top:20px;
}
```

When I inspect source code with Google Chrome developer tool, I can see that css is applied to the `.ad-title` and `ad-content` but these codes don't change anything.

So I've pasted everything I've done. can some one help me why Google Chrome behaves like that and doesn't show the text on the page under `.header'.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem. `ad-title` and `ad-content` are somehow matching some other internal css rules which don't belong to my application. When I change the names to `h-title` and `h-content` they started working fine.

Especially be careful, when you are using `AdBlock` extension since they don't like `ad` word.

Comment: If you encounter this problem somehow, this is the answer you might need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Chrome v. 8.0.552.224 and the text is displayed correctly... the problem is not in your html code...

Comment: I am using the same version `8.0.552.224` but I can't see anything at all.